# Why my confirm "alert" don't work on my code?

Tags: javascript, php, implementation

This is a page of a web app, and the job is simple:

I can see the "**alert**" that asks me whether I want to confirm or not. Based on the answer, I move to other pages.

If i sent my "**if**" cicle, the "alert" it's showed. This is the code

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../Model/gestoreAccessi.php');
include('connect.php');
?>
<script> 
let result = confirm("Sei sicuro di voler procedere?");
</script>
<script>
if(!result)
    result = <?php header('Location: http://www.teamjg.altervista.org/Matteo/navbar.php');?>
else
    <?php
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: http://www.teamjg.altervista.org/Matteo/index.html');
    ?>
</script>
```

Comment: things inside `<?php` tags are made on a server and outputted to the client on request. what's inside script tag is javascript. you cannot mix this to make a synchronous execution sequence. as what happens first is that first php draws things inside php tags to render the page, and only then javascript is executed. this is all wrong and there are so many wrong things that you are trying to do that it's difficult to answer your question at all. i suggest you complete some basic html/javascript and then php course to understand what's going on with your page

Comment: Thx for the answer. I am not yet good at web programming, because I started recently (less than a month), but I still need to proceed

Answer (score 1):

So, before I answer your question; just a note. PHP and Js will run on different machines (even though you're testing it on your localhost, still consider them as different machines)

All PHP code is run, and executed on the backend before anything is sent to your browser, after which js code is executed. PHP does not understand JS syntax, it will only look at `<?` and `?>` tags and execute everything inside them.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../Model/gestoreAccessi.php');
include('connect.php');
?>
<script> 
let result = confirm("Sei sicuro di voler procedere?");
</script>
<script>
if(!result)
    result = <?php header('Location: http://www.teamjg.altervista.org/Matteo/navbar.php');?>
else
    <?php
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: http://www.teamjg.altervista.org/Matteo/index.html');
    ?>
</script>
```

When this code is being sent by XAMPP (or whatever engine you use), the PHP is first executed which will make the code look like this:

```
// Session will be started
// contents of ../Model/gestoreAccessi.php will be copied and run
// contents of connnect.php will be copied and run
<script> 
let result = confirm("Sei sicuro di voler procedere?");
</script>
<script>
if(!result)
    result = //The header is already set
else
    // Location is already set
</script>
```

So this is undefined behaviour as you are sending two header tags with different locations, my best guess is it will redirect to `http://www.teamjg.altervista.org/Matteo/index.html`.

One thing you could do as a hotfix is set `window.location.href` if you want to redirect your user to some other website. Read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp).